# How to pull information from Sharepoint and display on a seperate website built with ASP.net and HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, asp.net, html, aspx

I have been tasked on creating an intranet website for my company. Currently we are using Office 365 SharePoint but my manager wants me to create a custom website which would be built on top of SharePoint. I am looking for ways on how to start. I am using sharepoint designer

What I want to achieve is, if a SharePoint list contains field ID, name, function, I want to retrieve these fields using ASP.net and then display these values in a aspx page in HTML table. The page will be custom built with CSS and jquery which I am not concerned about.

This is my sharepoint list:
[image: This is my sharepoint list]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Please just assist me with how to begin. I am good with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The reason people don't do this much is it forces them to have to implement their own security model (and assume the risk that goes with it) when SharePoint gives you this for free. Microsoft provided something called a provider-hosted app to supposedly handle this, but it turned out to be horribly executed, primarily because authentication/authorization is so tricky.

Not knowing anything about your security requirements I'd probably create an Azure AD app and use it to provide authentication to your custom website. Then I'd be able to fetch your data. If you don't need the security context of the logged in user you can use the .NET CSOM and a set of stored credentials to fetch your data. If you do need that then you'll probably have to figure out how to consume the SharePoint REST APIs using the auth tokens from Azure AD.

You can put away SharePoint Designer; it's not going to help. You're going to need Visual Studio for this. There are free versions available but if you don't know how to write .NET code you're going to be in quite a bit over your head.